# How to create tensor directly on GPU, or on device of another tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I found [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/construct-new-tensor-on-correct-device-based-on-input/469) discussion about this, in which the code

```
if std.is_cuda:
    eps = torch.FloatTensor(std.size()).cuda().normal_()
else:
    eps = torch.FloatTensor(std.size()).normal_()
```

becomes the nice

```
eps = std.new().normal_()
```

but it is said there that

> [The new() method is deprecated.](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3920)

---

1. How to create a new tensor directly on a specific device?
2. How to create a new tensor on the same device like another tensor without the ugly `if`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear now about this I think. [Here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor) are described the 4 main ways to create a new tensor, and you just have to specify the device to make it on gpu :

```
t1 = torch.zeros((3,3), device=torch.device('cuda'))
t2 = torch.ones_like(t1, device=torch.device('cuda'))
t3 = torch.randn((3,5), device=torch.device('cuda'))
```

And [this link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor.html#torch.tensor) adds further information about the `torch.tensor()` constructor. Again, the device is an argument to be specified.

If you want to use the device of another tensor, you can access it with `tensor.device`:

```
t4 = torch.empty((2,2), device=t3.device)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
torch.ones_like(std).normal_()
```

One of the parameters of `ones_like` is `device` which (from the docs) says:

> device (torch.device, optional) – the desired device of returned tensor. Default: if None, defaults to the device of input

You can also use `torch.zeros_like`